# facebook ads api python - how to remove the multi_share_end_card

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-ads-api

I'm using [facebook-python-ads-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk),and i have gone through the pertinent document:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/carousel-ads#spec

[image]

But i didn't find the **multi_share_end_card** class attribute.

```
class LinkData(ValidatesFields, AbstractObject):
    class Field(object):
        call_to_action = 'call_to_action'
        caption = 'caption'
        child_attachments = 'child_attachments'
        description = 'description'
        image_hash = 'image_hash'
        image_crops = 'image_crops'
        link = 'link'
        message = 'message'
        multi_share_optimized = 'multi_share_optimized'
        name = 'name'
        picture = 'picture'
```

Is this a bug?Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Try using the API directly or edit the SDK files to include the missing fields per your answer below - that SDK doesn't include all possible parameters or values and as you've seen here, trying to use it without that understanding can cause you problems in using the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a bug. ;-)

I solved the problem from [facebook-python-ads-sdk/issues/129](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-python-ads-sdk/issues/129#issuecomment-164683850).

At first,i tried:

```
link = LinkData()
link[LinkData.Field.link]              = link
link[LinkData.Field.call_to_action]    = call_to_action
link[LinkData.Field.child_attachments] = child_attachments
link[LinkData.Field.message]           = message
# remove the multi_share_end_card
link['multi_share_end_card'] = False
```

I got the following error:

```
FacebookBadObjectError: "multi_share_end_card" is not a valid field of LinkData
```

And then i tried

```
link = {
        'link': link,
        'call_to_action': call_to_action,
        'child_attachments': child_attachments,
        'message': message,
        'multi_share_end_card': False
    }
```

It works fine.